# Not able to compile grails project

Tags: grails

I am unable to clean, compile my individual grails project .
If I try running compile --stacktrace or --verbose on project 'X_Project' throws me the below error

Problem executing: compile --stacktrace
The command 'GrailsCommand(P/X_Project> --noreloading compile --stacktrace)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.

See details for the output produced so far.

If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time limit in the Grails preferences page.

See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch

```
Command: GrailsCommand(P/X_Project> --noreloading compile --stacktrace)
---- System.out ----
Loading Grails 2.2.3
---- System.err ----
Couldn't collect a stacktrace because Grails process was not found
------System.out:-----------
 Loading Grails 2.2.3
------System.err:-----------
```

Couldn't collect a stacktrace because Grails process was not found.

I'm a bit lost at the moment.Maybe someone can give me a hint about where to search for the error/problem.

Version am using  : Grails 2.2.3 , Groovy/Grails Tool Suite Version: 3.3.0.RELEASE.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that I would try is to run Grails project on it's own from a console. Make sure that your OS has correct path to grails installation. Go to the project folder and run: grails run-app

If it runs from console then you know the issue is in the IDE. Now you have a decision to make: run Grails project from console or use IDE - your choice. Here are my 2 cents:

Now I am not a big fan of Groovy/Grails Tool Suite in the first place. When I used Eclipse, I use to install Eclipse separately and then install Groovy & Grails plugins. This approach allows you to have a "standard" Eclipse without any restrictions and run Groovy & Grails without being constrained to a specific version. Now having said that you can try the approach.

If you don't want Eclipse, you can always use IntelliJ - it plays very well with Grails. IMHO it is working better with Grails than Groovy/Grails Tool Suite.